# x has type function but calling x gives a type error Python3

Tags: python, function, lambda, types, int

I have the following python statement

```
x = lambda :8()
```

checking the type of x returns the following

```
<class 'function'>
```

but then doing this

```
x()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I can solve this by putting parenthesis around the lambda like so

```
x = (lambda :8)()
```

But I am wondering what is going on.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you just experimenting or is there a goal here?

Comment: Yes, just experimenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not lie with calling `x`, you are trying to call `8` with `8()`. Calling an integer raises an error because instances of `int` are not callable.

> I can solve this by putting parenthesis around the lambda like so

What you are doing with `x = (lambda :8)()` is construct an anonymous function that always returns the number 8, then call it, and assign the name `x` to the return value.

```
>>> x = (lambda :8)()
>>> x
8
```

However, `x()` will still raise an error because again it's trying to call an integer.

```
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```